# iScroll stops working when I use Ajax to load the list

Tags: ajax, ipad, jquery, iscroll4, iscroll

I have an iScroll list set up and it work's perfectly fine when hard coded.

But when I use jQuery-Ajax to load in the exact same list, it sticks to the top and will not scroll down to the bottom.

```
$('#list1').load('lists/list1-1.html');
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem or know a solution.

I've used the Web Inspector to look at the DOM and the code for the list is the exact same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call to `refresh()` method after loading the list? You have to call the `refresh()` method when you modify the dimensions of the scrollable content, for example by adding items to a list. See section "Mastering the refresh() method" in [iScroll documentation](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4).

Comment: Just tried adding myScroll.refresh(); after loading the list but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: How are you creating the object `myScroll`?

Comment: var myScroll; myscroll = new iScroll('wrapper');